# Objective-c objects in C++ container

Tags: memory-management, objective-c++

Is it safe to place an Objective-C object in a C++ container?
For example:

```
@protocol MyProtocol <NSObject>
// Some properties.
@end

@interface MyInterface : NSObject< MyProtocol >
// some methods
@end

void foo() {
  std::vector<id<MyProtocol>> vec;
  MyInterface *interface = [[MyInterface alloc] init];
  vec.push_back(interface);
}
```

Will retain and release be Called on objects in the vector?

Comment: note that the compiler does not do ARC, that happens during runtime. And `init alloc` should be the other way around. And aren't you missing a `*` between `MyInterface` and `interface`?

Comment: @luk2302 I edited the question.

Comment: @luk2302: "note that the compiler does not do ARC, that happens during runtime" Nope. The compiler does it at compile-time.

Answer (score 0):

No, `std::vector` or any other collection will not call `retain` or `release` methods to Objective-C classes they contain references to.

You can create your own C++ smart pointer for Objective-C class and use it as proxy for `std` collections.

Here's a sample code to illustrate the idea:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <vector>

class ObjCPtr
{
public:
    ObjCPtr(id object) : _object(object)
    {
        [_object retain];
    }

    ObjCPtr(const ObjCPtr &original) : ObjCPtr(original._object) {}

    virtual ~ObjCPtr()
    {
        [_object release];
    }

    id object() const
    {
        return _object;
    }

protected:
    id _object;
};

@interface MyObject : NSObject
@end

@implementation MyObject
@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        MyObject *obj = [[MyObject alloc] init];
        NSLog(@"obj's rc=%lu", obj.retainCount); // Expecting: 1

        std::vector<ObjCPtr> vec;
        vec.push_back(ObjCPtr(obj));             // Wrap Obj-C object
        NSLog(@"obj's rc=%lu", obj.retainCount); // Expecting to be incremented

        [obj release];
        NSLog(@"obj's rc=%lu", obj.retainCount); // Expecting: 1
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
obj's rc=1
obj's rc=2
obj's rc=1
```

Please note that code above just shows the approach. It does not handle specific cases or scenarios.

Comment: Please can you explain why or add a reference to your answer?

Comment: "No, std::vector or any other collection will not call retain or release methods to Objective-C classes they contain references to." And why not?

Comment: Because there’s no magic in memory management. Std collections are designed in a way that makes them unaware of a nature of objects they contain. They rely on existance of proper handling helpers in terms of C++(copy constructors, assignment operators etc.). NSObject subclass is a foreign object to that collections and will be treated as regular void* pointer.